# Error message in r using ggpubr for ggscatter. undefined columns

Tags: r, ggpubr

```
ggscatter(df, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width",
               color = "Species", palette = c("black","green","magenta"),
               size = 3, alpha = 0.6)+
border()
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine with `iris` data

```
ggscatter(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width",
               color = "Species", palette = c("black","green","magenta"),
               size = 3, alpha = 0.6)+
border()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: This solved the undefined column error but created an error for an unknown sepal.length, sepal.width, and species

Comment: >Error in ggscatter(df, x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = "Species",  : 
  object 'Sepal.Length' not found

Comment: @SkylarGay Try with `the data `iris`.  Maybe your `df` data doesn't have those columns

Comment: ```Error in ggscatter(iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species,  : 
  object 'Species' not found``` still recieving the same error using the iris dataset

Comment: @SkylarGay i used `packageVersion('ggpubr')#
[1] ‘0.4.0’`